# Mono 3.2.0 Process Crashes on sgen-os-posix info handshake not met

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, task-parallel-library

I was previously running on Mono 2.10.9 on CentOS and I have a number of worker processes that run long-term running background work all the time. They typically will create a Task to report the current worker status to our database so we can keep track of processing speeds..etc. It's hard to tell exactly how/when the process crashes, but I know that at the very least I am using log4net to automatically append errors to the output. Anytime I see the following:

```
* Assertion at sgen-os-posix.c:60, condition `info->doing_handshake' not met
```

I can see that the process crashed. This didn't happen in 2.10.9, it only started happening when I upgraded to Mono 3.2. Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm not sure where to start on this one :/

Comment: Any code? How is the TPL related to the question? Is an exception thrown, and if so where? What is the stack trace?

Comment: that is definitely a bug, you should file it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: I don't receive a stacktrace at all unfortunately (which I know is hard to believe, but I just don't get anything). As a point of reference I'm also using ServiceStack.Redis' blocking pop mechanism. I went into the mono source and removed the explicit g_assert call and while the process didn't crash, my blocking pop stopped working apparently. There is something going on with my threads that is very hard to figure out :|

Comment: that is definitely a mono bug, you should file it in bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I have been experiencing the same behaviour, when using Mono 3.2 and ServiceStack. I have fallback to 2.10.8 for know. Have you filed the bug?

Comment: I have already filed the bug but it appears to be a private bug listed on bugzilla.xamarin.com until the Xamarin Team can address it. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13604

Comment: @CasperSlothPaulsen I can only reproduce my issue once every 12 hours or so, is there some easy test case that you can produce that will produce the same problem?

Comment: @nyxtom I did some further testing and found that my issue was due to a high workload, where lots of threads where created, which caused degraded memory allocations in the nursery.

Comment: Good news, looks like there might be a fix. Xamarin has responded to the bug and applied a potential fix to master.

Comment: The recent patch to mono on master has fixed this bug. I have been running stable much longer now than before. Very nice!